# Grafana Cloud Run set-up - intermittent timeout issues

Tags: grafana, google-cloud-run

I'm trying to set up a Grafana container with Cloud Run.

The high-level set-up is as follows:

- Cloud SQL for MySQL is used as database backend for Grafana
- The MySQL database user/password is fetched from Google Cloud Storage during container startup, then given to Grafana via environment variables.
- The Grafana application has dashboards that fetch data from the same MySQL instance.

Here is a simplified version of my current Dockerfile:

```
FROM grafana/grafana:6.5.2

USER root

WORKDIR /

COPY . .

RUN apk add --no-cache bash python3 python3-dev py3-pip \
    && pip3 install google-cloud-storage \
    && grafana-cli --pluginsDir "$GF_PATHS_PLUGINS" plugins install michaeldmoore-multistat-panel \
    && grafana-cli --pluginsDir "$GF_PATHS_PLUGINS" plugins install grafana-piechart-panel \
    && grafana-cli --pluginsDir "$GF_PATHS_PLUGINS" plugins install raintank-worldping-app \
    && grafana-cli --pluginsDir "$GF_PATHS_PLUGINS" plugins install briangann-datatable-panel \
    && grafana-cli --pluginsDir "$GF_PATHS_PLUGINS" plugins install grafana-clock-panel \
    && mkdir -p /config \
    && chown -R grafana:grafana /config /get_config.py /start.sh \
    && chmod +x /start.sh

USER grafana

ENTRYPOINT ["./start.sh"]
```

(The only difference to the real-world Dockerfile is that the real-world one includes some additional Grafana visualization plugins, but the problem is unlikely to be related to those.)

Here is the content of **start.sh**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

python3 get_config.py

GF_DATABASE_USER=$(cat /config/gf_database_user) \
GF_DATABASE_PASSWORD=$(cat /config/gf_database_password) \
./run.sh
```

In summary, start.sh does the following:

- Runs **get_config.py**, which gets database user and password from Google Cloud Storage and stores it locally at `/config/gf_database_user` and `/config/gf_database_password`;
- Runs Grafana with the database user/password values that were just populated from Google Cloud Storage

(note: run.sh is part of the `grafana/grafana:6.5.2` image).

Here is the content of **get_config.py**:

```
import os
import json
from google.cloud import storage

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = storage.Client()
    bucket = client.get_bucket(os.getenv('GCS_CONFIG_BUCKET'))

    blob = bucket.get_blob('grafana_database_config.json')
    grafana_database_config = json.loads(blob.download_as_string().decode('utf-8'))
    with open('/config/gf_database_user', 'w') as f:
        f.write(grafana_database_config['user'])
    with open('/config/gf_database_password', 'w') as f:
        f.write(grafana_database_config['password'])

    print("Got config files.")
```

The bucket name is given by the GCS_CONFIG_BUCKET environment variable, and the file is called `grafana_database_config.json`, with the following format:

```
{"user":"mysql_user_here","password":"mysql_password_here"}
```

Finally, deployment is done as follows:

**deploy_to_gcr.sh** - Build image in Google Container Registry

```
PROJECT_ID=project_id # Replace by actual project ID

gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/grafana-cloudrun-test --project $PROJECT_ID
```

**deploy_to_cloudrun.sh** - Deploy to Cloud Run

```
SERVICE_NAME=grafana-cloudrun-test

PROJECT_ID=project_id

# Replace by Cloud SQL instance name
CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE_NAME=project_id:us-central1:mysql_instance

# Replace by name of GCS bucket that stores grafana_database_config.json
GCS_CONFIG_BUCKET=grafana_cloudrun_test

# Replace by actual service URL
SERVICE_URL=https://$SERVICE_NAME-xxxx-ew.a.run.app

gcloud beta run deploy --image gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/grafana-cloudrun-test $SERVICE_NAME \
    --region europe-west1 \
    --project $PROJECT_ID \
    --platform managed \
    --set-cloudsql-instances $CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE_NAME \
    --allow-unauthenticated \
    --timeout 10m \
    --memory 1Gi \
    --set-env-vars "\
PROJECT_ID=$PROJECT_ID,\
GF_DATABASE_TYPE=mysql,\
GF_DATABASE_HOST=/cloudsql/$CLOUD_SQL_INSTANCE_NAME,\
GF_DATABASE_NAME=grafana_test,\ #  MySQL database name
GF_DATABASE_CONN_MAX_LIFETIME=1800,\
GF_SERVER_ROUTER_LOGGING=true,\
GF_LOG_LEVEL=debug,\
GF_SNAPSHOTS_EXTERNAL_ENABLED=false,\
GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL=$SERVICE_URL,\
GCS_CONFIG_BUCKET=$GCS_CONFIG_BUCKET,\
GF_SERVER_HTTP_PORT=8080"
```

This approach works mostly well. However, I've been seeing an intermittent error and I can't seem to figure out why it happens. Once in a while, the Cloud Run application hangs. Looking into the Cloud Run logs, we see cases where, for a few minutes, there are many consecutive requests ending with a 503 status, with the following text payload:

```
"The request failed because the HTTP connection to the instance had an error."
```

These 503 errors are typically followed by several consecutive requests ending with a 504 status because they reached the configured timeout (10 minutes).

Other than that, I can't seem to find any clear indication of what of what might be causing these problems.

(Note: Unfortunately, I've seen this happen only a couple of times outside production. I'm currently trying to reproduce it in an empty Grafana with just one dashboard using the default test data datasource. I will update this post if I see it happen in this case.)

Any clues?

Comment: Hi, I tried to reproduce it, but got many different errors, when building and deploying. When building I needed to add a "&& mkdir -p /var/www/html \" in the RUN in the Dockerfile, and create a "plugins" directory with something in it, I did "touch plugins/plugin1". Then when deploying I got "Container failed to start". Can you share a git repository where you have the "working" full program? Where is the database connection configured, apart from user and password?

Comment: @asbovelw - Thank you for the feedback. Sorry. I will put together a fully working example this week and update this post / get back to you.

Comment: @asbovelw - Hello - I made a big edit to the question where I removed some details and added others. I removed Nginx from the picture, because I'm no longer using it, and the problem still happens without it. Unfortunately, I can't include the complete application, but I've included more details about the setup and deployment. Thank you for the patience.